# Cocos2d: How to Align CCLabelTtf vertically with different font size?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

How to aligh two CCLabelTtf vertically with different font size? Thanks

This is how I am creating labels:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"11km 90m" fontName:@"Limelight.ttf" fontSize:20];
        label.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
        label.position = ccp((size.width-225)/2 + 30, size.height  - (size.height-260)/2 -i * 40 - 28);
         [self addChild:label];

        CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"2013/11/22" fontName:@"Limelight.ttf" fontSize:15];
        label1.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
        label1.position =  ccp(160 + 25, size.height  - (size.height-260)/2 -i * 40 - 28);
        [self addChild:label1];

        CCLabelTTF *label2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"21 : 00" fontName:@"Limelight.ttf" fontSize:10];
        label2.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
        label2.position =  ccp(size.width - ((size.width-225)/2 + 30) + 20, size.height  - (size.height-260)/2 -i * 40 - 28);
        [self addChild:label2];

    }
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: and what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: label1, label2 and label3 are not aligned because of the different size font, the biggest font size is the higher label is (a little bit higher)

Comment: @Yves I added a screen shot. Thanks

Comment: what version of cocos2d are you using ? it matters

Comment: cocos2d version 1.0.1

Comment: ah, hou may be cold out of luck.  I dont recall the details of the API at that version other than it was an issue. Try to see if you can create a texture using CCTexture2D , and later create the label with texture. You may have more control over the vertical alignment. Otherwise, i would encourage you to forklift to cocos2d version 2.1, where all this works (see my ... precipitous answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cocos2d 2.x, use the following :

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:inText
                                       fontName:_defaultMenuItemFont
                                       fontSize:_defaultMenuItemFontSize
                                     dimensions:inSize
                                     hAlignment:inAlignment

];
label.verticalAlignment = kCCVerticalTextAlignmentCenter;
```

i noticed that with one of the various 2.1 builds, you may have to do this AFTER setting the vertical alignment in order for it to work properly:

```
[label setString:inText];
```

Comment: well, work in 'debug' and all deprecated calls will be still functioning. Look in the 'ccDeprecated' class, for each deprecated API call it will show the appropriate replacement syntax. The one i find most annoying is the renaming of the .rect property to .activeArea ..... grrrrrrr. Did you look at CCTexture2D under 1.0.1 ?

Comment: Frankly no, I just started (One month). I think I should migrate

Comment: yes, especially if you dont have a large code base to migrate. And if this is your first objC stint, you may want to give ARC a try.